# Love2D walking animation play on key press without spritesheet

Tags: image, lua, love2d

Let's say you have three image files: `walkleft1.png`, `walkleft2.png` and `walkleft3.png`.
How do you use these images to play an animation while pressing a key?
Is there a way to do this without having to use a sprite sheet?

Left walking sprites:[image: img1][image: img2][image: img3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic way to do it is to make each texture correspond with a number. You can then store the stage of the animation and show the correct frame depending on the number, increasing it every certain number of milliseconds and resetting the number to 0 when it reaches the maximum value. I'm sure there are plenty of resources online that give examples. But, here's some pseudo-code to give you some ideas:

```
class animation
    stage = 0
    image_array = []        

    constructor(images)
        for image in images
           image_array.add_item(image)

    next()
        stage++
        if stage > image_array.length
            stage = 0
        return image_array[stage]
```

Then, call `next()` every time you want to update in your game loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy

```
function love.load()
img = {}
img[1] = love.graphics.newImage("sprite1")
img[2] = love.graphics.newImage("sprite2")
img[3] = love.graphics.newImage("sprite3")
frame = 1
anim_speed = 0
end

function love.update()
--only change the frame if anim_speed is equals to 20
if anim_speed == 20 then
if frame < 4 then
frame = frame + 1
else
frame = 1
end
--reset the anim_speed to 0 once it hits 20
anim_speed = 0
end
--increment the anim_speed, this gives delay effect between each frame
if anim_speed < 20 then
anim_speed = anim_speed + 1
end
end

function love.draw()
love.graphics.draw(img[frame])
end
```

With this script, the animation will change every 20 frames, code not tested.. let me know if it's not working